# Send local data to web application by double-click on file

Tags: javascript, php, session-variables

I have written a js-based web application which is used on my company internal network. With this application I can manipulate some data and store it as json-files with a proprietary file extension, those files are saved to local disk.
On my application I have an open-button which allows me to reload the data to the browser and continue work.

Now I would like to be able to double-click the files in Finder / File Explorer and have a browser window/tab opening and loading the data.

To do this, I figured out the following method which I want to submit to discussion:

- Create an application which is assigned to the proprietary file extension (this part is OS-specific, I consider it solved and not part of the question). This application is to be installed on all computers where *open-by-double-click* should be available.

  - On double-click the application loads the data in the file
  - the application asks the OS to open a specific URL, this will be a PHP-script and the json-data attached as GET parameter. --> Thus the browser is opened and data is sent to the server
- On the server, on the same domain as my application, the PHP script handles the data that it gets via GET

  - GET-data is stored to $SESSION
  - browser is redirected to the start-page of my web application
- The js-application itself is extended with a small fraction of code which checks with the server if any data is available in $SESSION. If there is any, it is loaded and treated as a file opened through a file-picker dialog.

Now, before I start coding, I would like to have some **feedback on my strategy. Is it a valid approach? Are there limitations? Are there better approaches?**

Here some points that I want to add, in order not to discuss about details

- File size can exceed the 4kB size limit for cookies
- Neither the web-application nor the "launch-application" are intended for sale or to be exposed to the WildWildWeb. They will only be used on the internal network
- Although not being publicly accessible, the web server uses a domain-name and a valid certificate
- If possible, I would prefer not to use any libraries / frameworks
- The *local disk* is really a file server, so the json-files are available also on other computers than the one they were created on

I'm not asking for any pieces of code, fiddles or ready-made examples

Comment: Question: How is this different to just creating a regular shortcut on the user's desktop which points to the URL of the PHP application?

Comment: `The js-application itself is extended with a small fraction of code which checks with the server if any data is available in $SESSION. If there is any, it is loaded and treated as a file opened through a file-picker dialog`...why would that need to be in the local JS application, and not part of the PHP script? JS can't check the PHP session directly anyway

Comment: @ADyson For every customer a different file is saved to disk. When double clicking on a file, I want to load only the data related to this customer. But actually including the json-data in the shortcut url could be a working approach (not so nice though, because I must drop my file extension)

Comment: @ADyson Sure, JS can't check the PHP session, but somehow I must get the data into my JS application. The PHP is only an utility to get the data from local disk to the browser.

Comment: This seems an odd way to do it...why is the customer data tied to a specific machine? Why not just ask them to log into the PHP application, and load/store all their data there? That is the way most/all web applications would handle such a scenario.

Comment: @ADyson The customer will not deal with this data, it's our salesmen that work on this data and store it to local disk (actually an internal file server, so the data is available on any workstation within the company network)

Comment: Ok but you described the data as "customer data", so that is the terminology I used in my reply. Even if the customers are not the people manipulating the data, it still doesn't appear to make any sense that you store the data locally and then transfer it to a web application. Why not just do all tasks in the PHP web application directly? Your suggested approach appears to just be overcomplicating the situation, but perhaps there is some reason for that which is not clear from what you've said so far.

Comment: Sorry my fault... Well the web application must be JS because it is using ThreeJS to render the products that the customers are interested in, call it a mini browser based CAD.
Of course the Data could be stored elsewhere (eg Database), but this would currently disrupt with other processes on how we treat data once a quote generates an order.